# Adding multiple namespaces to a xml file

Tags: xslt

I have a xml file and namespaces are given in the xml file. What I need to do is to use the namespaces given in the xml file only and qualify the xml file. Below is the sample xml file.

```
<Ticketing xmlns="ticketing.4.0" mfAction="BOOKING">
  <Reference>
    <Code>190</Code>
  </Reference>
  <BookingID>194283532</BookingID>
  <BookingCode>MCHOI190</BookingCode>
  <BookingDate>2011-04-21T15:40:04.000</BookingDate>
  <Persons>
    <Person>
      <Code>ADULT</Code>
      <Count>2</Count>
    </Person>
    <Person>
      <Code>CHILD</Code>
      <Count>2</Count>
    </Person>
  </Persons>
  <CreditCards>
    <CreditCard BookingType="BOOKING">
      <BookCreditCard xmlns="creditcard.3.0">
        <CardCode>VS</CardCode>
        <CardNumber>4444333322221111</CardNumber>
        <CardExpire>2011-12-31</CardExpire>
      </BookCreditCard>
    </CreditCard>
  </CreditCards>
</Ticketing>
```

I have to use the namespaces already present in the xml file and give them a prefix and qualify the xml with those namespaces. The output should be like below:-

```
<ticket:Ticketing xmlns:ticket="ticketing.4.0" mfAction="BOOKING">
  <ticket:Reference>
    <ticket:Code>190</ticket:Code>
  </ticket:Reference>
  <ticket:BookingID>194283532</ticket:BookingID>
  <ticket:BookingCode>MCHOI190</ticket:BookingCode>
  <ticket:BookingDate>2011-04-21T15:40:04.000</ticket:BookingDate>
  <ticket:Persons>
    <ticket:Person>
      <ticket:Code>ADULT</ticket:Code>
      <ticket:Count>2</ticket:Count>
    </ticket:Person>
    <ticket:Person>
      <ticket:Code>CHILD</ticket:Code>
      <ticket:Count>2</ticket:Count>
    </ticket:Person>
  </ticket:Persons>
  <ticket:CreditCards>
    <ticket:CreditCard BookingType="BOOKING">
      <credit:BookCreditCard xmlns:credit="creditcard.3.0">
        <credit:CardCode>VS</credit:CardCode>
        <credit:CardNumber>4444333322221111</credit:CardNumber>
        <credit:CardExpire>2011-12-31</credit:CardExpire>
      </credit:BookCreditCard>
    </ticket:CreditCard>
  </ticket:CreditCards>
</ticket:Ticketing>
```

Can someone suggest how to implement this. 
Thanks
Rudra

Comment: Is it right, what `<Ticketing/>` and `<BookCreditCard/>` tags are without namespaces?

Comment: Why `Ticketing` opening tag is without namespace, while the closing tag is with? The same is for `BookCreditCard`. I you mean `<ticket:Ticketing xmlns:ticket="ticketing.4.0" mfAction="BOOKING">` and `<credit:BookCreditCard xmlns:credit="creditcard.3.0">`

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a general solution that can work with any number of namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure is the best way to do it. But it does the job:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="*">
   <xsl:element name="ticket:{name()}" namespace="ticketing.4.0">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
   </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="BookCreditCard|BookCreditCard//*"">
  <xsl:element name="credit:{name()}" namespace="creditcard.3.0">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 1.0 there is no guaranteed solution, because implementations are free to use any prefix in the output file that they want. However most processors do the reasonable thing, and @empo's solution will therefore usually work. In XSLT 2.0 it is guaranteed to work.

I would be inclined to use the namespace to control which template is chosen, something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ticket="ticketing.4.0" xmlns:credit="creaditcard.3.0">

 <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="ticket:*">
   <xsl:element name="ticket:{local-name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
   </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="credit:*">
  <xsl:element name="credit:{local-name()}">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

**A more general solution** (no hardcoded prefixes and can work with any number of namespaces):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name=
  "{substring(namespace-uri(),1,6)}:{local-name()}"
       namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Ticketing xmlns="ticketing.4.0" mfAction="BOOKING">
    <Reference>
        <Code>190</Code>
    </Reference>
    <BookingID>194283532</BookingID>
    <BookingCode>MCHOI190</BookingCode>
    <BookingDate>2011-04-21T15:40:04.000</BookingDate>
    <Persons>
        <Person>
            <Code>ADULT</Code>
            <Count>2</Count>
        </Person>
        <Person>
            <Code>CHILD</Code>
            <Count>2</Count>
        </Person>
    </Persons>
    <CreditCards>
        <CreditCard BookingType="BOOKING">
            <BookCreditCard xmlns="creditcard.3.0">
                <CardCode>VS</CardCode>
                <CardNumber>4444333322221111</CardNumber>
                <CardExpire>2011-12-31</CardExpire>
            </BookCreditCard>
        </CreditCard>
    </CreditCards>
</Ticketing>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<ticket:Ticketing xmlns:ticket="ticketing.4.0" mfAction="BOOKING">
   <ticket:Reference>
      <ticket:Code>190</ticket:Code>
   </ticket:Reference>
   <ticket:BookingID>194283532</ticket:BookingID>
   <ticket:BookingCode>MCHOI190</ticket:BookingCode>
   <ticket:BookingDate>2011-04-21T15:40:04.000</ticket:BookingDate>
   <ticket:Persons>
      <ticket:Person>
         <ticket:Code>ADULT</ticket:Code>
         <ticket:Count>2</ticket:Count>
      </ticket:Person>
      <ticket:Person>
         <ticket:Code>CHILD</ticket:Code>
         <ticket:Count>2</ticket:Count>
      </ticket:Person>
   </ticket:Persons>
   <ticket:CreditCards>
      <ticket:CreditCard BookingType="BOOKING">
         <credit:BookCreditCard xmlns:credit="creditcard.3.0">
            <credit:CardCode>VS</credit:CardCode>
            <credit:CardNumber>4444333322221111</credit:CardNumber>
            <credit:CardExpire>2011-12-31</credit:CardExpire>
         </credit:BookCreditCard>
      </ticket:CreditCard>
   </ticket:CreditCards>
</ticket:Ticketing>
```

**Do note**: The first 6 characters of the namespace-uri of each element are used for the prefix of the corresponding generated name. Therefore this solution works correctly as long as the starting 6 characters of any namespace-uri of an element obey the sintactical rules for **[NCName](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/REC-xml-names-20091208/#NT-NCName)**.

Comment: The generalized solution is working awesomely great. Thanks everybody for the help. I have to study a lot more on xslt.